# Equivalent of WAR file in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a system written in Lisp that runs state machines.  I'd like to dynamically load the definition of the state machine and any required assets (images, etc) from a directory, given just the name of the directory.  There will be multiple different state machines.  This is similar, but not identical, to Apache loading and running a WAR file.

My concern is that simply compiling and loading a file could run literally anything.  Ideally I'd like to get just the state machine definition, configure it with the path to the assets, and have it available to execute.  Right now I'm playing around with loading a class that implements a particular base class, but that's not straightforward.  Is there a standard technique for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can loading and running a WAR file not run literally anything?

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying you're worried about the possibilities of arbitrary code execution from reading in a file? I so you should look into redefining the read-table to exclude unwanted symbols.

For an example checkout [this](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html), look for 'SAFE-READ-FROM-STRING'.

It's not complete but then you can use #'read to get the datastructure, do some sanity check and compile if you need to.

If this isn't what you were looking for then my apologies, would you be able to explain further what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think your link goes where you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to safe-read-from-string.  That might be part of the solution.  I think I'll have to implement my own dynamic loading approach that looks for a class that subtypes a known class and exposes the user specific state machine definition.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to read definition of a state machine without executing arbitrary code, you may consider the following macro:

```
(defmacro def-state-machine (name (&rest assets) &rest states)
  `(defparameter ,name
     (list
       :assets ',(remove-if-not #'legal-asset? assets)
       :states ',(remove-if-not #'legal-state? states))))
```

which will create list of valid assets and states (since I don't know, how your machine looks like, I'm putting some abstract predicates here - they may check for legal syntax, or if argument is of the certain type, or e throw an error if asset or state are illegal).

Let's assume, you also need to define some function to run machine:

```
(defmacro def-transition (name args &body body)
  `(defun ,name (,@args)
     ,@body))
```

Separate macro for defining function allows additional sanity checks. Finally, you may define reader function:

```
(defun load-toy-state-machine (directory)
  (let ((path (cl-fad:merge-pathnames-as-file directory #P"machine.lisp"))
        ;(*readtable* (copy-readtable nil))
       )
    ; (make-dispatch-macro-character #\#)
    (with-open-file (stream path :direction :input)
      (do ((form (read stream nil 'done)
                 (read stream nil 'done)))
          ((eql form 'done) T)
        (if (member (car form) '(def-state-machine def-transition))
            (eval form)
            (error "malformed state machine definition file"))))))
```

Which will eval only allowed macros (def-state-machine and def-transition), which have fixed syntax, and may contain additional sanity checks. Neither of these executes code.

Comment: No it doesn't. If you want to disable reader macros, you need to modify readtable. I've added comment in load-toy-state-machine, which uncommented throws an error on any #\# encountered.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks!  I may incorporate those into my solution since there doesn't seem to be anything that already exists.  I appreciate your time.